# The method not visible error: JSTL deliver request to JSP without going through servlet

Tags: servlets

It said The method setName(String) from the type Person is not visible. However, I thought this method is actually from Employee. Any help is appreciated.

The error message is : 
type Exception report

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /TestBean.jsp
The method setName(String) from the type Person is not visible
1: <jsp:useBean id="person" type="foo.Person" class="foo.Employee" >
2: </jsp:useBean>
3: <% person.setName(request.getParameter("userName")); %>
4: Person is created by useBean tag : 
5: <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" />


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.39 logs.
```

TestBean.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" type="foo.Person" class="foo.Employee" >
</jsp:useBean>
<% person.setName(request.getParameter("userName")); %>
Person is created by useBean tag : 
<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" />
```

Employee Class

```
package foo;
public  class Employee extends Person
{
    public Employee(){
    }

    String name="";
    public void setName(String name){

    this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName(){
    return name;
    }

     String namecolor ="red";
    public  void setNameColor(){
    this.namecolor=namecolor;
    }
     public String getNameColor()
    {
    return namecolor;
    }
}
```

Person Class

```
package foo;
public abstract class Person implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public Person(){
    }
    String name="";
      abstract void setName(String name);
      abstract String getName();

    String namecolor ="red";

    public  void setNameColor(){
    this.namecolor=namecolor;
    }
     public String getNameColor()
    {
    return namecolor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the following code in your `TestBean.jsp` file?

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="foo.Employee" />
<jsp:setPropery name="person" property="userName" value="Some Name") />
```

Your problem could be caused by trying to set properties on your bean by calling the setter directly instead of using the `jsp:setProperty` tag in my code sample above.

Comment: Actually the code is from HF jsp and servlet. Your code appears in book already and works. Later, the author said "<% person.setName(request.getParameter("userName")); %>" in TestBean.jsp  also works. The author also said: "she can do it with a combination of standard actions and scripting".However, it does not and give error message by Tomcat. 

You mention about "set properties on your bean by calling the setter directly " will cause the error. Could you give a detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't know why the scriptlet fails when you call `<% person.setName(...); %>`, because it should work.  But it is considered bad practice and a violation of the bean pattern to invoke bean methods directly.